# Merge and match using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to Merge and match using Pandas

**Data**

df1

```
ID      name    stat    
aa678   TRUE    112 
aa678   FALSE   111 
bb131   TRUE    122
```

df2

```
ID2     Box
aa678   santa fe
cc121   delux
```

**Desired**

```
ID      name    stat    Box
aa678   TRUE    112     santa fe
aa678   FALSE   111     santa fe
bb131   TRUE    122
```

**Doing**

```
df1.join(df2.set_index('ID'), on = 'ID2')
```

However, this is not giving the desired result and not showing the values that do not have matches.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `merge` which does the same thing but offers more flexibility:

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on="ID", right_on="ID2", how="left")
```